# Digital Numbers to Top of Atmosphere Radiance for Landsat 8, which formula is suitable?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, landsat, digital-image-processing

I read from the following article, **https://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/8/5/413** that in order to convert Landsat 8 Digital Numbers to TOA Radiance, equation (1) is used (attached image). For some other Landsat versions, equations (2), (3) are used instead (attached image). Another article like this **https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0016706120303074** uses equation (3) of the attached image in order to convert Landsat 8 Digital Numbers to TOA Radiance.

- These 2 articles are using different equation in order to calculate the same conversion for
  Landsat 8, is one of them wrong?
- Which is the correct equation of converting Digital Numbers to Top of Atmosphere Radiance for
  Landsat 8?
- About the offset calibration "Qi", I found from this website **https://www.usgs.gov/landsat-missions/landsat-8-oli-and-tirs-calibration-notices** that for example, a -0.29 +/- 0.12 should be applied to Band 10. In the USGS site **https://www.usgs.gov/landsat-missions/using-usgs-landsat-level-1-data-product**, they are not including -Qi in the equation of conversion Digital Numbers to TOA Radiance. Should I still apply it even if they don't have it on the formula?

[image: Image 1: Article about converting Digital Numbers to TOA Radiance]

Comment: Why not just download the OLI surface reflectance product? It is now a standard product on EarthExplorer. Landsat now goes through a standard processing workflow that results in Analysis Read Data (ARD) so, much of the historic pre-processing is unnecessary. Just make sure that you have surface reflectance selected in your download bundle. If using an API, just select the correct product.

Comment: Make sure that you select Collection 2 - Level 2 (https://www.usgs.gov/centers/eros/science/usgs-eros-archive-landsat-archives-landsat-8-9-olitirs-collection-2-level-2) as your landsat query product.

Comment: My question is, after the selection of Collection 2 - Level 2 do I just download my desired image or should I do something else in the item basket? I downloaded a file just to check and there are some tiffs with this name "LC08_L2SP_183034_20220728_20220802_02_T1_SR_B1". So this Band 1 for instance have surface reflectance? @JeffreyEvans

Comment: Yes. If you look at the product documentation you will see that it is delivered as surface reflectance. This is an additional processing step to at-sensor reflectance, which is what you are detailing in your post. The surface reflectance is what you are after.

Comment: Also, my question was about surface radiance. Did you inform me about reflectance for a specific reason? I am new to this field so that's why I am asking. @JeffreyEvans

Comment: Why do you want radiance as it is functionally a processing stepping-stone to at-sensor reflectance and atmospheric correction? All of this pre-processing, including cloud masking and surface reflectance, has been done in the level 2 products. For scene normalization and temporal harmonization this is the product you want. Historically, you had to do all of this pre-procesisng yourself but, now it is done is done in the collection 2 level 2 USGS workflow. In the data you downloaded the "SR" in the name string is surface reflectance. Anything more an we need to move this into the chat.

Comment: I am trying to compute Land Surface Temperature and the first step is to find at-sensor radiance using the digital numbers of a given ".tiff" file. So, that's why I need at-sensor radiance. May you please inform, what do you suggest me to do in order to calculate the Land Surface Temperature with Collection 2 - Level 2? @JeffreyEvans

Comment: Look at the product description link for collection 2 level 2 data that I provided in a previous message, it clearly indicates that LST in included in the collection along with a link for additional information on LST.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140987/discussion-between-chris-and-jeffrey-evans).

Comment: This could also be useful: https://yceo.yale.edu/how-convert-landsat-dns-top-atmosphere-toa-reflectance